# Sort ArrayList with custom comparison

Tags: c#, asp.net, arrays, sorting

I am trying to sort an `ArrayList` using c#. When the `ArrayList` contains comparable objects, it is possible to sort with using `list.Sort()` but I need to sort an `ArrayList` which contains non-comparable objects. For example, let's say the object is `Ring` and it has an attribute property `Price`. Then I need to sort the `ArrayList` to the price order. If is is possible to select ascending or descending that will more helpful. Thank You!

> Blockquote

arrAtdMon = **(ArrayList)**hashTb[unixMon];

if (arrAtdMon != null)
  monCount = arrAtdMon.Count;

int[] arrayMax = { monCount, tueCount, wedCount, thuCount, friCount };

int maxValue = arrayMax.Max();

KidAttendance valMon = null;
string monTagName = string.Empty;

> Blockquote

above array list is to be sorted it self.

Comment: Could you please share the code for the arrayList? Show us what it contains and what you need to achive.

Comment: Do all of these objects have a price? Do they share an interface or a base class that exposes that price property?

Comment: You have to implement IComparable to define you want to sort on price and optionally implement IComparer to pass to sort to tell the order of sorting.

Comment: ArrayList is effectively deprecated. Is there a reason why you have to use it?

Comment: Ok, now  I have added few statements of the original code

Answer (score 3):

You can do this by implementing [IComparer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.icomparer(v=vs.110).aspx) interface:-

```
public class Ring : IComparer
{
    public decimal Price { get; set; }

    public int Compare(object x, object y)
    {
        return ((Ring)x).Price.CompareTo(((Ring)y).Price);
    }
}
```

Working [Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/fIkyRG).

Answer (score 2):

First, you really should be using the `List<T>` class, not `ArrayList`. Doing so wouldn't solve your problem, but it would make the code less fragile and more easy to maintain.

As for the specific question, you want to do something like this…

Assume:

```
class Ring { public decimal Price { get; set; } }
```

Then:

```
ArrayList list = ...; // Initialized as some collection of Ring instances

list.Sort(Comparer.Create((r1, r2) => r1.Price.CompareTo(r2.Price)));
```

This creates a new `Comparer` instance using the `Comparison<T>` of `(r1, r2) => r1.Price.CompareTo(r2.Price)`. That is, for each pair of objects being compared, compare the price of the first with the price of the second.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that these objects share a base class or an interface with the price property you should be able to do something like this:

```
// Base class with price property, could also be an shared interface
public abstract class Product
{
    public decimal Price{get;set;}
}

public class Ring : Product
{

}
public class Bag : Product
{

}

// Some test data
var myUnsortedArray = new Product[]{new Ring{Price = 1.2m}, new Bag{Price=2.5m}};

// Easy sort with LINQ
var sortedProducts = myUnsortedArray.OrderBy(p => p.Price).ToArray();
var sortedProductsDescending = myUnsortedArray.OrderByDescending(p => p.Price).ToArray();
```

**UPDATE**

I just realised that the question is about ArrayLists and have the changed solution below:

```
// Some test data
var myUnsortedArrayList = new ArrayList{new Ring{Price = 1.2m}, new Bag{Price=2.5m}};

// Easy sort with LINQ
var sortedProducts = myUnsortedArrayList.OfType<Product>().OrderBy(p => p.Price).ToArray();
var sortedProductsDescending = myUnsortedArrayList.OfType<Product>().OrderByDescending(p => p.Price).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

To sort an set of objects, the object needs to be Comparable and you can set up the comparison you'd like in the CompareTo() method:
[IComparable information here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.icomparable.compareto(v=vs.110).aspx)